# Code for this expression in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to code this expression in python but I'm having some difficulty.

[image]

This is the code I have so far and wanted some advice.

```
 x = 1x2 vector
 mu = 1x2 vector
 Sigma = 2x2 matrix 

 xT = (x-mu).transpose()
 sig = Sigma**(-1)
 dotP = dot(xT ,sig )
 dotdot = dot(dotP, (x-mu))
  E = exp( (-1/2) dotdot  )
```

Am I on the right track? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Sigma ** (-1)` isn't what you want. That would raise each element of `Sigma` to the `-1` power, i.e. `1 / Sigma`, whereas in the mathematical expression it means the inverse, which is written in Python as `np.linalg.inv(Sigma)`.
- `(-1/2) dotdot` is a syntax error; in Python, you need to always include `*` for multiplication, or just do `- dotdot / 2`. Since you're probably using python 2, division is a little wonky; unless you've done `from __future__ import division` (highly recommended), `1/2` will actually be `0`, because it's integer division. You can use `.5` to get around that, though like I said I do highly recommend doing the division import.
- This is pretty trivial, but you're doing the `x-mu` subtraction twice where it's only necessary to do once. Could save a little speed if your vectors are big by doing it only once. (Of course, here you're doing it in two dimensions, so this doesn't matter at all.)
- Rather than calling `the_array.transpose()` (which is fine), it's often nicer to use `the_array.T`, which is the same thing.
- I also wouldn't use the name `xT`; it implies to me that it's the transpose of `x`, which is false.

I would probably combine it like this:

```
# near the top of the file
# you probably did some kind of `from somewhere import *`.
# most people like to only import specific names and/or do imports like this,
# to make it clear where your functions are coming from.
import numpy as np

centered = x - mu
prec = np.linalg.inv(Sigma)
E = np.exp(-.5 * np.dot(centered.T, np.dot(prec, centered)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Im getting an error - ValueError: matrices are not aligned
at E = exp(-.5 * dot(c.T, dot(InvSig, c)))

Comment: Note that you could simplify the `E` expression using matrix multiplication: `centered=(x-mu).view(np.matrix);prec=np.linalig.inv(Sigma).view(np.matrix); E=np.exp(-0.5 * centered.T * prec * centered)`